# Anonymous procedure PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := ( ; not null range default character

Tags: sql, oracle, anonymous-methods

here's the code:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee7da/4247


CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
(
 id int primary key, 
 type varchar2(20), 
 details varchar2(40)
)
/

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(id, type, details)
VALUES
(1, 'Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com')

/

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(id, type, details)
VALUES
(2, 'Twitter', '@sqlfiddle')


DECLARE
 x supportContacts.type%type;
 y supportContacs.details%type;
BEGIN 
  select type,details into x,y from supportContacts where id = 1;
  dbms_output.put_line(x);
  dbms_output.put_line(y);
END; 
/
```

i wonder why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change query terminator symbol with bottom right button (like combobox);
See proof
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f93f7/3/0)

Answer (score 3):

This:  `y supportContacs.details%type;`

Should be: `y supportContacts.details%type;`

If I make that change, it works for me.

Comment: ah okay, my bad XD

do you know if sqlfiddle can output put_line

Comment: Don't know, never used it. Can you do "set serveroutput on"?

Comment: Then I would say it probably isn't supported. You should build another table to send your "output" to and select from it to see your results.